# Why do callback addresses change when passing the same function from JavaScript to Android native (via cordova bridge)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've written a cordova plugin that registers a callback function for an event.

Here is how the Javascript code registers a function:

```
 window.MultiWindowPlugin.registerOnStop(pauseHandler);
```

In Java land, I print out the context address just to see what is going on. It prints out this:

```
08-22 14:40:44.767 23957 24031 D MultiWindowPlugin: onStart() cb = org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext@91375f8
```

All good. The handler is also called when an event happens.

Now, right after that `registerOnStop` command above, I call:

```
window.MultiWindowPlugin.deregisterOnStop(pauseHandler);
```

`deregister` is the opposite of `register`. However, the callback address for the *same* function is different.

```
08-22 14:40:52.448 23957 24031 D MultiWindowPlugin: onStop() cb = org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext@3b1eeb
```

Why is this the case? I was hoping I could simply use the callback address to add/remove the callbacks.

(Note: My plugin has the ability to register multiple callbacks for the same event, hence I cannot just nullify the callback handler variable in java land - its an ArrayList of callbacks)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed my situation by passing a string identifier during registration from JS land to Java land and using that identifier to remove the specific callback handler. Not an answer to my question, but a workaround to the situation. Not going to mark this as an accepted answer.